# Typescript react redux - Error with connect

Tags: typescript, react-redux

Novice at this and following patterns from [JavascriptServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) site which uses Typescript with React/Redux amoung others.

Mine is a React Redux project.

I have a menu tsx file that displays a menu that is largely unaltered from the boilerplate offering from JavascriptServices called "NavMenu.tsx"

I wanted to use a couple of state variables "IsAuthorised" & "username". These are in redux state and I want to just use them not set them etc.

I am getting the following error on the connect statement at the bottom and in particular (NavMenu) is red underscored and have no idea how to fix this error?

> [ts]
>   Argument of type 'typeof NavMenu' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component & LoginState>'.
>     Type 'typeof NavMenu' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent & LoginState>'.
>       Type 'typeof NavMenu' provides no match for the signature '(props: DispatchProp & LoginState & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement'.

Here is the code for the NavMenu class - the error is on the very last line:

```
  import * as React from "react";
  import { NavLink, Link } from "react-router-dom";
  import {
    Navbar,
    Nav,
    NavItem,
    NavDropdown,
    MenuItem,
    Glyphicon
  } from "react-bootstrap";
  import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";
  import { connect } from "react-redux";
  import { ApplicationState } from "../store";
  import * as LoginState from "../store/Login";

  // At runtime, Redux will merge together...
  type NavMenuProps = LoginState.LoginState;

  export class NavMenu extends React.Component<NavMenuProps, {}> {
    public render() {
      return (
        <div className="main-nav">
          <div className="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div className="navbar-header">
              <button
                type="button"
                className="navbar-toggle"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target=".navbar-collapse"
              >
                <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span className="icon-bar" />
                <span className="icon-bar" />
                <span className="icon-bar" />
              </button>
              <Link className="navbar-brand" to={"/"}>
                JobsLedger_API
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="clearfix" />
            <div className="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                  <NavLink exact to={"/"} activeClassName="active">
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-home" /> Home
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/counter"} activeClassName="active">
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-education" /> Counter
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={"/fetchdata"} activeClassName="active">
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" /> Fetch data
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.login // Selects which state properties are merged into the component's props
  )(NavMenu) as typeof NavMenu;
```

[image]

EDIT

I note the 1st comment but need someone to expand on it.

The file I was following in the JavascriptServices example is below. I have followed their connect syntax.. there was no mention of mapStateToProps in that example...

Here it is:

```
            import * as React from 'react';
        import { Link, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
        import { connect } from 'react-redux';
        import { ApplicationState }  from '../store';
        import * as WeatherForecastsState from '../store/WeatherForecasts';

        // At runtime, Redux will merge together...
        type WeatherForecastProps =
            WeatherForecastsState.WeatherForecastsState        // ... state we've requested from the Redux store
            & typeof WeatherForecastsState.actionCreators      // ... plus action creators we've requested
            & RouteComponentProps<{ startDateIndex: string }>; // ... plus incoming routing parameters

        class FetchData extends React.Component<WeatherForecastProps, {}> {
            componentWillMount() {
                // This method runs when the component is first added to the page
                let startDateIndex = parseInt(this.props.match.params.startDateIndex) || 0;
                this.props.requestWeatherForecasts(startDateIndex);
            }

            componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: WeatherForecastProps) {
                // This method runs when incoming props (e.g., route params) change
                let startDateIndex = parseInt(nextProps.match.params.startDateIndex) || 0;
                this.props.requestWeatherForecasts(startDateIndex);
            }

            public render() {
                return <div>
                    <h1>Weather forecast</h1>
                    <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server and working with URL parameters.</p>
                    { this.renderForecastsTable() }
                    { this.renderPagination() }
                </div>;
            }

            private renderForecastsTable() {
                return <table className='table'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                            <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                            <th>Summary</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {this.props.forecasts.map(forecast =>
                        <tr key={ forecast.dateFormatted }>
                            <td>{ forecast.dateFormatted }</td>
                            <td>{ forecast.temperatureC }</td>
                            <td>{ forecast.temperatureF }</td>
                            <td>{ forecast.summary }</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>;
            }

            private renderPagination() {
                let prevStartDateIndex = (this.props.startDateIndex || 0) - 5;
                let nextStartDateIndex = (this.props.startDateIndex || 0) + 5;

                return <p className='clearfix text-center'>
                    <Link className='btn btn-default pull-left' to={ `/fetchdata/${ prevStartDateIndex }` }>Previous</Link>
                    <Link className='btn btn-default pull-right' to={ `/fetchdata/${ nextStartDateIndex }` }>Next</Link>
                    { this.props.isLoading ? <span>Loading...</span> : [] }
                </p>;
            }
        }

        export default connect(
            (state: ApplicationState) => state.weatherForecasts, // Selects which state properties are merged into the component's props
            WeatherForecastsState.actionCreators                 // Selects which action creators are merged into the component's props
        )(FetchData) as typeof FetchData;
```

Comment: Your `mapStateToProps` function must return an object , aka `{...}`

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Dummy is correct. Per the Redux docs:

> **[mapStateToProps(state, [ownProps]): stateProps] (Function)**: If this argument is specified, the new component will subscribe to Redux store updates. This means that any time the store is updated, mapStateToProps will be called. **The results of mapStateToProps must be a plain object**, which will be merged into the component’s props. If you don't want to subscribe to store updates, pass null or undefined in place of mapStateToProps.

Within `mapStateToProps` you are mapping parts of a Redux store to a local `prop` **which you need to define**. Most `mapStateToProps` calls look like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        login: state.login
    };
};
```

Now the `prop` `login` is mapped to the `login` value in your Redux store. I am equally confused by the above code because `state.weatherForecasts` is not being assigned to any `prop` and therefore should not be accessible. I see they use a prop called `forecasts` but it's impossible to tell from their `interface` definition if that `prop` is handed down from the parent or supposed to be part of their `store`. I would stick with using `mapStateToProps` in the above way - it's pretty standard in the community and behaves consistently with TS.